# Llamado a modal según condición en success AJAX

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, modal

Necesito condicionar el llamado a una cortina Modal según sea la condición, he intentado de la siguiente forma, me llama ambas ventanas a la vez:

```
/*Modal Edit */  
  $(document).on("click", ".editAsig", function () {
    //RECEPCIONO LOS PARAMETROS Y ASIGNO A VARIABLES;
    var proy = $(this).data('proy');
    var nomproy = $(this).data('nomproy');
    var zon = $(this).data('zon');
    var num = $(this).data('num');   
    var mue = $(this).data('mue');
    var _token = $('input[name="_token"]').val();
    //AQUI CON AJAX VOY AL CONTROLADOR CON LARUTA INDICADA 
    $.ajax({
      url:"..............",
      method:"POST",
      data:{proy:proy, zon:zon, num:num, mue:mue, _token:_token},  
      success:function(result)
      {
        //OBTENGO RESULTADOS Y SEGÚN ELLO EL MODAL QUE QUIERO MOSTRAR
        if(result == 0){

          //MUESTRO EL MODAL PARA EDITAR LOS REGISTROS
          $(".modal-header #nomproy").text(nomproy);
          $('#editAsig').modal('show');

        }else if(result == 1 ){
          //SI EXISTE UN REGISTRO DEBO MOSTRAR OTRO MODAL Y PARA EVITAR QUE APAREZCA EL MODAL CON FORM DE EDITAR USO LA ETIQUETA DE ABAJO
          $('#editAsig').remove();
          $('#modalAlert').modal('show'); 
        }
      }
    });       
  });
```

Me ocurre que cuando obtengo los resultados si "`result==1`" muestra ambas ventanas modal y si es "`result==0`" va bien y solo muestra: `$('#editAsig').modal('show');`

Acá agrego el HTML de donde llamo mi código antes citado:

```
<td>
  <a href="" data-ruta="" data-id="" data-proy="" data-nomproy="
" data-zon="" data-num="" data-mue="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editAsig" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary editAsig" title="Editar"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>
</td>
```

Comment: Hola, ¿podrías agregar también el código html del problema?

Comment: Qué es eso de `Eliminar");`?, ahi parece que cierras comillas, pero nunca las abriste. Además, después del punto y coma del `moda('show');` parece que falte parte del código o algo.

Comment: @ArianJM disculpa se me fue ese "Eliminar", omtitelo; la línea termina en:  $('#modalAlert').modal('show');

Comment: @the-breaker cito el código a continuación       ======== ===                 <td>
  <a  href="" data-ruta="" data-id="" data-proy="{{$reg->Relpromue_fk_proy}}" data-nomproy="{{$qryProy->proy_nom}}" data-zon="{{$reg->Relpromue_zon}}" data-num="{{$reg->Relpromue_num}}" data-mue="{{$reg->Relpromue_mue}}" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editAsig" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary editAsig" title="Editar">  
  <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> 
 </a>                      
</td>

Comment: No no, agrégalo a la pregunta, lo puedes hacer con la opción "editar" debajo de la pregunta

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puede ser que tengas algún mal cierre de etiquetas `div` en tu código y eso provoque el problema.  Posibles Problemas:

1. Verificar usar para cada modal `<div class="modal" id="diferente_siempre">`.
2. Si usas `.modal("show")` remover el `data-target`.
3. Usar para el `if` el `===` para validar estrictamente por tipo de dato.

Mira agrego un ejemplo con tu caso, código replicado de [Bootstrap - Modal](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/modal/#modalshow)

```js
function getAsyncModal(){
   let result = Math.random(0,1) > 0.5 ? 1 : 0
   console.log(result)
   showModal(result)
}

function showModal(result){
   if(result === 0){
      $('#exampleModal').modal('show')
   } else if(result === 1){
      $('#exampleModal2').modal('show')
   }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<button type="button" onclick="getAsyncModal()">Modal Aleatorio</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="showModal(0)" >If 0</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="showModal(1)" >If 1</button>


<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar 0</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">OK</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar 1</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">OK</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Gracias no es la solución que necesito, mi solución va dada por solo un botón, explico:
El usuario da click a un botón, con "$(document).on("click", ".editAsig", function ()"  tomo los datos que están en el enlace y a travéz de ajax me voy al controlador, según el resultado que tenga del success debe ser el modal que voy a mostrar.

Comment: Hé mejorado la respuesta, agregando validacion segun si `result` es `0` o `1`, para este caso funciona, revisa en tu codigo los `div` de cierre, uso ademas el `===` para que la comparacion sea extrica con el tipo de dato porque `false == 0  da verdadero` pero `false === 0 da falso`

Comment: Gracias Diego Mesa, muy amable. tu ejemplo me ha servido para entender bien lo que ocurría y es que desde uso un ID en el botón donde llamo al modal quien a su vez tiene el mismo ID por eso se me cargaba SI o SI el modal con el FORM de edición independiente del resultado que obtuviera.

Comment: Ok, para evitar eso puede hacer un `event.stopPropagation()` o `event.prevendDefault()`, ya que muestras los modalas usando javascript con `.modal('show')` a los botones les debes remover el `data-target` y pues si verificar usar `id` distintos, osea para cada `<div class="modal" id="diferente_siempre">`